# unresolved external symbol "" referenced in function _main

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am having trouble regarding three functions called within my main function in my program/game: initEnemy, drawEnemy, and updateEnemy. Each have this error attached to them at runtime: "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "..." referenced in function _main"

The function calls are underlined in red in my main function, and when highlighted over say this: "Error: more than one instance of overload function "..." matches the argument list:"

If anyone could help me to understand what the problem is, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_ttf.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "objects.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

//GLOBALS==============================
const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 675;
const int NUM_BULLET = 5;
const int NUM_ENEMY = 5;

enum STATE{TITLE, PLAYING, LOST};
enum KEYS{UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, SPACE, W, A, S, D};
bool keys[9] = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};

int vx = 25;
int shipvy = 15;
int runnervy = 15;

int i;

int middleRect_x1 = 0;
int middleRect_x2 = WINDOW_WIDTH;
float middleRect_y1 = (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) - 40;
float middleRect_y2 = (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) + 40;

float minJumpThing = (WINDOW_HEIGHT - middleRect_y2) / 2;

int playerScore = 0;
int playerLives = 0;

//function prototypes

void initRunner(Runner &runner);
void minimumGravRunner(Runner &runner);
void drawRunner(Runner &runner);
void runnerJump(Runner &runner);
void runnerFall(Runner &runner);
void stopRunner(Runner &runner);

void initShip(Ship &ship);
void drawShip(Ship &ship);
void moveShipUp(Ship &ship);
void moveShipDown(Ship &ship);
void stopShipBrick(Ship &ship);
void stopShipWindow(Ship &ship);

void initBullet(Bullet bullet[], int bulletSize);
void drawBullet(Bullet bullet[], int bulletSize);
void fireBullet(Bullet bullet[], int bulletSize, Ship &ship);
void updateBullet(Bullet bullet[], int bulletSize);

void initEnemy(Enemy &enemy, int enemySize);
void drawEnemy(Enemy &enemy);
void updateEnemy(Bullet bullet[], int enemySize, Enemy &enemy);

int main(void)
{
    //primitive variable
    bool done = false;
    bool redraw = true;

    float gameTime = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    int gameFPS = 0;

    Ship ship;
    Runner runner;
    Bullet bullet[5];
    Enemy enemy;

    //object variables

    //Allegro variables
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *arial = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *dosapp = NULL;

    //Initialization Functions
    if(!al_init())                                      //initialize Allegro
        return -1;

    display = al_create_display(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);           //create our display object

    if(!display)                                        //test display object
        return -1;

    al_init_primitives_addon();
    al_install_keyboard();
    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();
    al_init_image_addon();

    event_queue = al_create_event_queue();
    timer = al_create_timer(1.0 / 60);

    arial = al_load_font("arial.ttf", 18, 0);
    dosapp = al_load_font("dosapp.fon", 40, 0);

    initBullet(bullet,NUM_BULLET);
    initRunner(runner);
    initShip(ship);
    initEnemy(enemy, NUM_ENEMY);

    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));

    al_start_timer(timer);
    gameTime = al_current_time();
    while(!done)
    {
        ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
        al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &ev);

        if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
        {
            if(keys[UP])
            {
                runnerJump(runner);
            }
            if(runner.y1 <= middleRect_y2 - 10)
            {
                runnerFall(runner);
                keys[UP] = false;
            }
            if(!keys[UP])
            {
                if(runner.y1 < (WINDOW_HEIGHT - 40))
                    runnerFall(runner);
                else if(runner.y1 >= runner.minimumJump - 40 && runner.y2 >= runner.minimumJump &&
                    runner.y1 != (WINDOW_HEIGHT - 40) && runner.y2
                    != WINDOW_HEIGHT)
                {
                    keys[UP] = true;
                    runnerJump(runner);
                }
            }
            if(keys[W])
                moveShipUp(ship);
            if(keys[S])
                moveShipDown(ship);
            if(ship.y1 <= 0)
                stopShipWindow(ship);
            else if(ship.y2 >= middleRect_y1)
                stopShipBrick(ship);
            if(keys[SPACE])
                drawBullet(bullet,NUM_BULLET);

            updateBullet(bullet,NUM_BULLET);
            updateEnemy(bullet,NUM_ENEMY,enemy);
        }
        else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE)
        {
            done = true;
        }
        else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
        {
            switch(ev.keyboard.keycode)
            {
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                    done = true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
                    if(runner.y1 == (WINDOW_HEIGHT - 40) && runner.y2 == WINDOW_HEIGHT)
                        keys[UP] = true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
                    keys[DOWN] = true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_W:
                    keys[W] = true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_S:
                    keys[S] = true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_SPACE:
                    if(!bullet[i].live)
                    {
                        keys[SPACE] = true;
                        fireBullet(bullet, NUM_BULLET, ship);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP)
        {
            switch(ev.keyboard.keycode)
            {
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                    done = true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
                    //if(runner.y1 <= runner.minimumJump - 40 && runner.y2 <= runner.minimumJump)
                        keys[UP] = false;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
                    keys[DOWN] = false;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_W:
                    keys[W] = false;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_S:
                    keys[S] = false;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_SPACE:
                    keys[SPACE] = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(redraw && al_is_event_queue_empty(event_queue))
        {
            al_draw_filled_rectangle(middleRect_x1, middleRect_y1, middleRect_x2, middleRect_y2, al_map_rgb(255,255,255));
            al_draw_textf(arial,al_map_rgb(0,0,0),WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) - 20,ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE,"Score: %d",
                playerScore);
            al_draw_textf(arial,al_map_rgb(0,0,0),WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) + 13,ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE,"Lives: %d",
                playerLives);
            drawShip(ship);
            drawRunner(runner);
            drawBullet(bullet,NUM_BULLET);
            if(enemy.live = true)
                drawEnemy(enemy);

            al_flip_display();
            al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
        }
    }
    al_destroy_event_queue(event_queue);
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    al_destroy_font(arial);
    al_destroy_font(dosapp);
    al_destroy_display(display);                        //destroy our display object

    return 0;
}

void initRunner(Runner &runner)
{
    runner.ID = RUNNER;
    runner.x1 = 10;
    runner.x2 = runner.x1 + 40;
    runner.y1 = WINDOW_HEIGHT - 40;
    runner.y2 = runner.y1 + 40;
    runner.minimumJump = (middleRect_y2 + minJumpThing) + 45;
}
void drawRunner(Runner &runner)
{
    al_draw_filled_rectangle(runner.x1,runner.y1,runner.x2,runner.y2, al_map_rgb(255,255,255));
}
void runnerJump(Runner &runner)
{
    runner.y1 -= runnervy;
    runner.y2 -= runnervy;
}
void runnerFall(Runner &runner)
{
    runner.y1 += runnervy;
    runner.y2 += runnervy;
}
void stopRunner(Runner &runner)
{
    runner.y1 = (WINDOW_HEIGHT - 40);
    runner.y2 = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
}
void initShip(Ship &ship)
{
    ship.ID = SHIP;
    ship.x1 = 10;
    ship.x2 = ship.x1;
    ship.x3 = ship.x1 + 40;
    ship.y1 = (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) / 4 + 50;
    ship.y2 = ship.y1 + 40;
    ship.y3 = ship.y1 + 20;
}
void drawShip(Ship &ship)
{
    al_draw_filled_triangle(ship.x1,ship.y1,ship.x2,ship.y2,ship.x3,ship.y3,al_map_rgb(255,255,255));
}
void moveShipUp(Ship &ship)
{
    ship.y1 -= shipvy;
    ship.y2 -= shipvy;
    ship.y3 -= shipvy;
}
void moveShipDown(Ship &ship)
{
    ship.y1 += shipvy;
    ship.y2 += shipvy;
    ship.y3 += shipvy;
}
void stopShipWindow(Ship &ship)
{
    ship.y1 = 0;
    ship.y2 = 40;
    ship.y3 = 20;
}
void stopShipBrick(Ship &ship)
{
    ship.y1 = middleRect_y1 - 40;
    ship.y2 = middleRect_y1;
    ship.y3 = middleRect_y1 - 20;
}
void initBullet(Bullet bullet[], int bulletSize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < bulletSize; i++)
    {
        bullet[i].ID = BULLET;
        bullet[i].speed = 20;
        bullet[i].live = false;
        keys[SPACE] = false;
    }
}
void drawBullet(Bullet bullet[], int bulletSize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < bulletSize; i++)
    {
        if(bullet[i].live)
        {
            al_draw_filled_circle(bullet[i].x,bullet[i].y,2,al_map_rgb(255,255,255));
            keys[SPACE] = false;
        }
    }
}
void fireBullet(Bullet bullet[], int bulletSize, Ship &ship)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < bulletSize; i++)
    {
        if(!bullet[i].live)
        {
            bullet[i].x = ship.x3;
            bullet[i].y = ship.y3;
            bullet[i].live = true;
            keys[SPACE] = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void updateBullet(Bullet bullet[], int bulletSize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < bulletSize; i++)
    {
        if(bullet[i].live)
        {
            bullet[i].x += bullet[i].speed;
            if(bullet[i].x >= WINDOW_WIDTH)
                bullet[i].live = false;
        }
    }
}
void initEnemy(Enemy enemy, int enemySize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < enemySize; i++)
    {
        std::default_random_engine y1_generator;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> y1_distribution(0,middleRect_y1);
        enemy.ID = ENEMY;
        enemy.live = true;
        enemy.x1 = WINDOW_WIDTH + 50;
        enemy.x2 = enemy.x1 + 40;
        enemy.y1 = y1_distribution(y1_generator);
        enemy.y2 = enemy.y1 + 40;
        enemy.speed = 20;
    }
}
void drawEnemy(Enemy enemy)
{
    al_draw_filled_rectangle(enemy.x1,enemy.y1,enemy.x2,enemy.y2,al_map_rgb(255,0,0));
}
void updateEnemy(Bullet bullet[], int enemySize, Enemy enemy)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < enemySize; i++)
    {
        if(enemy.live)
        {
            std::default_random_engine y1_generator;
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> y1_distribution(0,middleRect_y1);
            enemy.x1 = WINDOW_WIDTH + 50;
            enemy.x2 = enemy.x1 + 40;
            enemy.y1 = y1_distribution(y1_generator);
            enemy.y2 = enemy.y1 + 40;
            enemy.x1 -= enemy.speed;
            enemy.x2 -= enemy.speed;
            if(bullet[i].x == enemy.x1 && bullet[i].x == enemy.x2 - 40 && bullet[i].y >= enemy.y1 && bullet[i].y <= enemy.y2)
                enemy.live = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forward declaration `void initEnemy(Enemy &enemy, int enemySize);` doesn't match `void initEnemy(Enemy enemy, int enemySize) {}`.

Comment: looks like DCoder is on something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because, as @DCoder says, you forward declare the functions with a slightly different signature as your definitions. This led the compiler to assume they are two different functions, hence the error.

Change the definitions as below to fix it. (basically add all the `&` symbols to the `Enemy` variables that you have missed)

```
void initEnemy(Enemy& enemy, int enemySize)  
{


void drawEnemy(Enemy& enemy)
{

void updateEnemy(Bullet bullet[], int enemySize, Enemy& enemy)
{
```

Comment: Ahhhh, a very silly and careless mistake on my part. Thanks so much.